# Antd Menu.SubMenu keeps collapsing on hover

Tags: antd

I am having trouble with the Antd submenu. If I use the code below, the submenu opens on hover, but it will close again if the mouse is not exactly hovering the link in the first item.

Any idea what I can do about this? I'm using v3.0.0-beta.5

Here is a screen recording:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdxakivocf5atgs/antd-submenu-bug.mov?dl=0

Maybe it's just a bug in the beta version, but submitting an issue to the antd repo requires a lot of effort unfortunately and doesn't even include 3.0 in their app and fork boilerplate.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Menu, Avatar } from 'antd';
const { SubMenu, Item, Divider } = Menu;
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Box = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 64px;
`;

interface INavigationProps {
  onLogout: () => any;
  isAuthed: boolean;
  avatar?: string;
}

export const Navigation: React.SFC<INavigationProps> = ({
  isAuthed,
  onLogout,
  avatar,
}) =>
  isAuthed && (
    <Menu mode="horizontal" style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}>
      <Item key="admin">
        <Link to="/admin">admin</Link>
      </Item>
      <SubMenu
        key="user"
        mode="inline"
        title={
          <Box>
            <Avatar src={avatar} icon="user" />
          </Box>
        }
      >
        <Item key="user.profile">
          <Link to="/profile">profile</Link>
        </Item>
        <Divider />
        <Item key="user.logout">
          <Link to="/" onClick={onLogout}>
            logout
          </Link>
        </Item>
      </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
  );

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug of 3.0 but in 2.13.x looks like working fine, https://codepen.io/kossel/pen/XzpqbE?&editors=001.

Comment: I've since receive a response with a boilerplate for 3.0 beta on codepen. Hopefully I find some time soon to replicate the bug there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has since disappeared after upgrading (now beta.6)